# Bad CPU type in executable after modifying usr/bin

Tags: iphone, linux, terminal, jailbreak

I moved a folder into `usr/bin` because it was in my $PATH variable and I have come to believe that was a bad choice.

Now I can't access the root file structure to revert the change bc terminal won't establish a prompt (bad cpu type error) and I tried to access it via ssh but I get a

> ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed error.

Are there any other ways to modify the file structure?

Comment: Sorry for your pain, but this is probably off-topic for StackOverflow. IF you can edit your Q to contain the exact commands you used (`cd`s and everything) , you might get help here or from http://unix.stackexchange.com  (use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there). As is, there are too many unknowns to tell. Also clarify your Q to indicate, "Do you still have a shell/terminal window open to that machine?". .....

Comment: And after your crisis is over, please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Arg, just noticed your tags iphone and jailbreak! Maybe you better to to http://apple.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling bash from Cydia solved this issue for me.